# Dropping trigger in the external database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am a new in ms sql server and faced with the problem: i can't  drop a trigger in the database that is external to my current database.

So, I have 2 databases -CRM (main) and CrmHistory(where the history information is held).
In CrmHistory database I am writing some API to manage the gathering of the history information.
One of the task is to create\drop triggers in Crm database.
Here is my SP:

```
create procedure [dbo].[DropHistoryTriggers]    
as
begin

set nocount on;

 declare @sql table(s varchar(1000), id int identity)
 declare @SqlStr nvarchar(max)=''       

 insert into @sql(s)
   select 'drop trigger '+  name from Crm.sys.triggers 
    where name like '%History' 

select @SqlStr=@SqlStr+s+' ' +char(13) from @sql

if (@SqlStr!='')
execute (@SqlStr)

end
```

While executing it, I get "Cannot drop the trigger 'trndshistory', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

Both databases is owned by 'sa'.I create and execute SP also using 'sa' login.

How I tried to solve this issue:

1. Set  the TRUSTWORTHY property to ON on both databases.
2. When I specified "with execute of owner\sa\self" I got the same error.
3. I created another login, then create 2 users mapping to this login in both databases and granted  AUTHENTICATE in the target database. Then I specified "execute as" in SP to impersonate this user.It doesn't help me, to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are pulling the triggers from a catalog view in the database crm, but then trying to drop them from the current database. To execute in the context of the other database, you can use:

```
EXEC crm.dbo.sp_executesql @SqlStr;
```

As an aside, probably much easier to do this without a @table at all (uncomment the EXEC line when you are confident it is doing what it should):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DropHistoryTriggers]    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

    SELECT @sql += 'DROP TRIGGER ' 
        + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ';' + CHAR(13)
        FROM crm.sys.triggers AS t
        WHERE t.name LIKE '%History';

    PRINT @sql;
    --EXEC crm.dbo.sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

Comment: It does not work. As for using tables : it is a common solution that works good in more complex scenarios- geting scripts for creating tables, for example.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Getting scripts for creating tables can also be assembled without stuffing temporary results into a table, btw.

Comment: Using "SELECT 'DROP TRIGGER crm.dbo.' " + name ... or " EXEC crm.dbo.sp_executesql @SqlStr;" I am getting the same error- "Cannot drop the trigger 'trndshistory', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

Comment: I am getting the  "'DROP TRIGGER' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name." when the trigger is specified by "database.schemd.trigger_name"

Comment: Ok, so you're going to have to stick with the `EXEC cmd.dbo.sp_executesql` method to execute the drop commands in the context of that database. Now it is either a schema prefix issue, or it really is a permissions issue. I've updated the code to ensure the trigger name is prefixed with the right prefix, so if that still doesn't work, then it must be a permissions issue...

Comment: Your solution with "EXEC crm.dbo.sp_executesql @SqlStr;" helped me after all. I think that the reason why "execute @SqlStr" doesn't work is that there is no way to specify the  full name of the trigger. E.g. "database.schema.trigger_name". For example, if i try to  drop a table  named like 'set @SqlStr='drop table Crm.dbo.Nds2' execute @SqlStr works fine.  P.S crm.sys.triggers doesn't have a schema_id column, and there is now way to create a trigger whith the schema that differs from the schema of underlying table.

Comment: Sorry my bad about the schema... knee-jerk reaction I guess. I'll correct the code sample, but I still think it should be done without the @table variable...